# Pick random values from a dataframe such that resultant dataframe is unique within two columns in python-pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the dataframe:

```
data = [['G1','P1',0.3], ['G1','P2',0.3], ['G1','P3',0.3],['G2','P1',0.3],['G2','P2',0.3],['G3','P2',0.3]] 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['GT', 'PRED','ACC'])
```

df2 looks like this :

```
    GT  PRED    ACC
0   G1  P1      0.3
1   G1  P2      0.3
2   G1  P3      0.3
3   G2  P1      0.3
4   G2  P2      0.3
5   G3  P2      0.3
```

The objective is to pick random rows such that values in GT and PRED are picked uniquely.
From other stack overflow searches, I have the following code:

```
size = 1        # sample size
replace = False # with replacement
fn = lambda obj: obj.loc[np.random.choice(obj.index, size, replace),:]
pt = df2.groupby('PRED', as_index=False).apply(fn)
```

whose output is

```
    GT  PRED    ACC
0   G1  P1      0.3
1   G1  P2      0.3
2   G1  P3      0.3
```

My expected output should be

```
    GT  PRED    ACC
0   G1  P3      0.3
1   G2  P1      0.3
2   G3  P2      0.3
```

That is at the time of filtering we are ensuring that GT and PRED are unique. I can ensure this by applying function after df generation in a for a loop . I wanted to avoid this.

Comment: `df2.groupby(['GT','PRED'], as_index=False).apply(fn)`?

Comment: Wont work . This will not ensure that GT and PRED are individually unique. G2 will appear twice in the result

Comment: Your original df does not have all possible combinations of GT and PRED. Using a purely random selection is possible to miss some valid combination. Are you fine with that?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a way.

1. Make arrays with unique values of `'GT'` and `'PRED'` columns. They can be obtained using the [unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) method.
2. Use `numpy` [shuffle](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) to shuffle each array (this will give you randomness).
3. Make a dataframe `pairs` using the shuffled arrays. Each row of this array will be a pair of randomly chosen `'GT'` and `'PRED'` unique values.
4. With pandas `apply` and some boolean logic, search which rows in `df2` have a valid `'GT'` and `'PRED'` pair, i.e. a pair which is present in the `pairs` dataframe.
5. Select those rows only from `df2` to obtain your output.

Translated in a working code, this is:

```
gt_u = df2['GT'].unique()
pred_u = df2['PRED'].unique()

np.random.shuffle(gt_u)
np.random.shuffle(pred_u)

pairs = pd.DataFrame({'GT':gt_u, 'PRED':pred_u})    
#pairs = pd.DataFrame([[x, y] for x, y in zip(gt_u, pred_u)], columns=['GT', 'PRED'])

sel = df2.apply(lambda x : (x[['GT', 'PRED']] == pairs).all(axis=1).any(axis=0), axis=1)
out = df2.loc[sel]
```

Note: if you are not sure that the unique arrays will be of equal length, use the commented line to generate `pairs`.